# Help to get driver for Tenda wireless wifi adapter (AX300 w311mi)

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

I have bought a Wifi adapter which is Tenda AX300 (w311mi). But i can't able to run on my ubuntu machine due to lack of proper driver.

when i typed lsusb on my pc, it shows: **Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2604:0013 Tenda AIC8800DC**

I have also tried one of the tutorial following [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495004/installing-tenda-w311mi-usb-adabter-on-ubuntu-22-04)

But it didn't work. Chipset of this adapter is AIC8800. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is ID 2604:0013 and not 2604:0012?

Comment: yes it is...2604:0013

Comment: the chipset is "AIC 8800" may be

Comment: Have you tried this post first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495004/installing-tenda-w311mi-usb-adabter-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/0013/' RS=`

Comment: There is no output (or empty)

Comment: Voting to reopen as the wireless script would have provided no valuable info in this case

Answer (score 2):

Try in terminal

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lynxlikenation/aic8800.git
cd aic8800/drivers/aic8800
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
```

Check `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled for the module to work

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this wifi adapter too and here's what I did.

You are using [Tenda W311MI v6.0](https://www.tendacn.com/product/w311miv6.html) hence you should download the driver for the v6.0 version [here](https://www.tendacn.com/download/detail-4785.html).
There's a *how-to-install* **documentation** inside a PDF in the downloaded file but I'll explain my way below.

1. Plug in your wifi adapter. If your system recognized it as a USB, eject it from file explorer.
2. Extract the downloaded file and open the folder.
3. Open the **x86** folder and install the **.deb** package inside it using command `sudo dpkg -i w311miv6-pkg-v1.0.0-amd64.deb`
4. Wait until the installation process is finished. The wifi should work without rebooting.

For additional information, I'm using Linux Mint 20.3 MATE.

Answer (score -1):

You can also install driver as a deb package
[enter link description here](https://www.tenda.com.cn/download/detail-3764.html)

Comment: So that actually worked?  It didn't build on my 6.5 kernel